# Blowing the trumpets during individual calamity

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, behaalotcha-parsha, tragedy, chatzotzerot-trumpets

Numbers 10:9 command kohanim blow silver trumpets during war, [the Sefer Hachinuch](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.384.1) codifies it during times of calamity in general. My question is, if kohanim know individuals or small groups or family who are going through calamity would this obligation apply like it does during times of collective calamity (such as this war, wars in general, national destruction etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to specifically be a law when the tzibbur at large is experiencing trouble

משנה תורה דפוסים תעניות א':א
מִצְוַת עֲשֵׂה מִן הַתּוֹרָה לִזְעֹק וּלְהָרִיעַ בַּחֲצוֹצְרוֹת עַל כָּל צָרָה שֶׁתָּבוֹא עַל *הַצִּבּוּר*. שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר עַל הַצַּר הַצֹּרֵר *אֶתְכֶם* *וַהֲרֵעֹתֶם* בַּחֲצֹצְרוֹת (במדבר י':ט'). כְּלוֹמַר כָּל דָּבָר שֶׁיָּצֵר לָכֶם כְּגוֹן בַּצֹּרֶת וְדֶבֶר וְאַרְבֶּה וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּהֶן זַעֲקוּ עֲלֵיהֶן וְהָרִיעוּ:

Answer (score 1):

The MAGEN AVRAHAM (beginning of OC 576) wonders why it is not the practice to blow the Shofar on publicly decreed fast days nowadays. Reb Moshe In Igros Moshe says its only in the time of Beis Hamikdash. The Chizkuni in Parshas Behaloscha says that the Chatzotzros are blown so Hashem should remember the Zchus of Korbanos which also have Chatzotzros blown when they are brought. This would seem in line with the Igros Moshe that it should be the same Chatzotzros that are used at Hakravas Korbonos and nowadays that we don't have those we dont blow.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Rambam ([*Hilchot Ta'aniyot* 2:2](https://rambam.alhatorah.org/Main/Taaniyot/2.2#m7e1n6)), this is a commandment for communal troubles, such as that affect a city:

> כל עיר שיש בה צרה מכל אלו, אותה העיר מתענה ומתרעת עד שתעבור הצרה, וכל
> סביבותיה מתענות ולא מתריעות, אבל מבקשים עליהם רחמים.
>
> A city afflicted by any of these difficulties should fast and sound
> the trumpets until the difficulty passes. The inhabitants of the
> surrounding area should fast, but should not sound the trumpets. They
> should, however, ask for mercy on [their brethren's] behalf.

(Note also that the Rambam only seems to explicitly mention a specific role for the Kohanim with regard to the sounding of the trumpets, when it is done in Jerusalem, on the Temple Mount [see *Hilchot Ta'aniyot* 4:15-17]. Likewise, he does not appear to explicitly require that trumpets in response to communal distress need to be made of silver [contrast [*Hilchot Klei HaMikdash* 3:5](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1008228/jewish/Chapter-3.htm); see also [*Hilchot Issurei Mizbei'ach* 4:7]](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Things_Forbidden_on_the_Altar.4.7?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi). The [*Mishneh LaMelech*](https://rambam.alhatorah.org/Full/Kelei_HaMikdash/3.5#e0n6) suggests that the Rambam holds like the view of the Tosafists that the Levite's trumpets could be made of any material.)